# Tensorflow How to correctly pass input values for prediction to the neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm having trouble while trying to pass values for prediction to my neural network. Here is the code snippet:-

```
model=keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[14])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Notice my `input_shape=[14]`

I'm getting errors while trying to make predictions using each of the following ways:-

```
print(model.predict(40,8,1,2,0,2,6,10,34,40,16,23,67,25))
TypeError: predict() takes from 2 to 9 positional arguments but 15 were given

print(model.predict([40,8,1,2,0,2,6,10,34,40,16,23,67,25]))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)

print(model.predict([[40,8,1,2,0,2,6,10,34,40,16,23,67,25]]))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (14,) but got array with shape (1,)

print(model.predict[(40,8,1,2,0,2,6,10,34,40,16,23,67,25)])
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

print(model.predict([40],[8],[1],[2],[0],[2],[6],[10],[34],[40],[16],[23],[67],[25]))
TypeError: predict() takes from 2 to 9 positional arguments but 15 were given
```

However, it works with the following way:-

```
X_train,  X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 0.2, shuffle=True)
pred=model.predict(X_test)
```

Here is a screenshot of X_test when printed `print(X_test)`

[image]

And this is a snippet of my dataset:-

[image]

And here is the entire code:-

```
import glob
import os
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras as k
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow import lite

df = pd.read_csv("kidney4.csv")
df = df.dropna(axis=0)

for column in df.columns:
        if df[column].dtype == np.number:
            continue
        df[column] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[column])

X = df.drop(["classification"], axis=1)
y = df["classification"]

x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_scaler.fit(X)
column_names = X.columns
X[column_names] = x_scaler.transform(X)

X_train,  X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size= 0.2, shuffle=True)

model=keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[14])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500)

for model_file in glob.glob("kidney_final_2.model"):
  print("Model file: ", model_file)
  model = load_model(model_file)
  pred=model.predict(X_test)
  pred = [1 if y>=0.5 else 0 for y in pred] #Threshold, transforming probabilities to either 0 or 1 depending if the probability is below or above 0.5
  scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
  print()
  print("Original  : {0}".format(", ".join([str(x) for x in y_test])))
  print()
  print("Predicted : {0}".format(", ".join([str(x) for x in pred])))
  print() 
  print("Scores    : loss = ", scores[0], " acc = ", scores[1])
  print("---------------------------------------------------------")
  print()
```

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

The problem/trick with the "`model.predict()`" in Keras and TensorFlow is that **you can only predict on batches**.

Therefore, in order to predict on one data point(in your case an array of 14 elements), you need to simulate the batch axis. That is, a batch of size 1, since you want to predict on one data point.

You can use `numpy` to achieve this.

```
input_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
input_array_for_prediction = np.expand_dims(input_array,axis=0)
print(model.predict(input_array_for_prediction))
```